# Unity3D Repeating pattern applied 2D Mesh with collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

What is the proper way of creating 2D Mesh with collider?
All I want to do is create some shapes (not very simple like triangle or rectangle) like slide or rounded rectangle. And I want to define a repeating pattern inside it to fill and reduce memory. Lastly I will need a collider around my shape.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a particular part you're having trouble with?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not know how to start. All I can do is to import a picture and add a polygon collider. Is there any way to create mesh in editor? Because it seems very difficult define vertices in script for each shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the entire thing in a modeling program like Blender... same as you would for a 3D model, but all of your shapes/meshes will be flat.  Create your textures the same also... all in your modeling program.  Then save your file (.blend for Blender) to your Unity assets folder.  Now switch back to Unity and drag/drop the prefab that is created form the .blend file on to your scene.  Change the renderer if you want (I use Mobile Unlit, or Unlit Transparent most of the time).

Works just like a normal 2D sprite now... but the texture will repeat and you can make whatever shape you want in your modeling program.

For the collider, you can add any type of collider you want.  If your shape isn't standard, you'll probably want an Edge Collider 2D or a Polygon Collider 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following:

1. Create a polygonCollider2D directly in unity as you need it
2. Add a mesh filter and a mesh renderer
3. Add a custom script made by yourself, in which you convert the Collider polygon to a mesh (Mesh that will be used on your MeshFilter at runtime).
   3.1. In order to do this, just copy the vertices of the polygon
   3.2. Use the triangulator class in this link to help you create your mesh (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator)
4. Enjoy

If you want to see the custom script find it here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/835675/how-to-fill-polygon-collider-with-a-solid-color.html